# How to scan built docker images using trivy in gitlab-ci pipeline?

Tags: dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, buildah, trivy

I am trying to write a gitlab-ci script to build images from dockerfiles, scan them using Trivy and push them to my private registry. I've used the below script, and it works fine when i use it to pull docker images, scan them and push to my registry but it gives an error when i use it on custom built images

```
if gcloud artifacts docker images list $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$image --include-tags | grep -q $version; then
    echo "Image $image:$version already exists in the repository. Skipping build and push."
else
  cd $path;
  buildah build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$image:$version .;
  echo "Image : $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$image:$version"

  # Scan the image with Trivy and set exit code 1 for critical vulnerabilities
  trivy image --severity CRITICAL --exit-code 1 --no-progress $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$image:$version

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    # Push the image to the Docker registry using Buildah
    buildah push "$DOCKER_REGISTRY/$repository:$tag"
    echo "buildah push "$DOCKER_REGISTRY/$image:$version""

    echo "Image $image:$version has been pushed to the artifact registry"
  else
    echo "Image $image:$version contains critical vulnerabilities. Skipping build and push."
  fi
fi
```

The error:

```
2023-09-19T05:35:27.513Z    INFO    Need to update DB
2023-09-19T05:35:27.514Z    INFO    Downloading DB...
2023-09-19T05:35:32.992Z    FATAL   scan error: unable to initialize a scanner: unable to initialize a docker scanner: 3 errors occurred:
* unable to inspect the image (asia-west-docker.pkg.dev/v2/project-circles/dataplatform/buildah-image:1.0.1): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
* unable to initialize Podman client: no podman socket found: stat podman/podman.sock: no such file or directory
* GET https://asia-west-docker.pkg.dev/v2/project-circles/dataplatform/buildah-image/manifests/1.0.1: MANIFEST_UNKNOWN: Failed to fetch "1.0.1"
```

**Note : I am using buildah:v3.1 image in my gitlab-ci pipeline**

Please help me to identify what I'm doing wrong here and what i need to do to fix it?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Maybe check the docker daemon is running on the runner machine.

Comment: im running a buildah image. i dont think i have docker installed on the runner

Comment: @LARA that is what your problem is - if the buildah image doesn’t have docker then you would either need to install it or find an image which does have it I think